# How to make a list with sections

Tags: enumerate, indentation

I want to make a list with sections, that is, having labels between some lists.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
text (without indent)
    \item some item
    \item some more item
text (without indent)
    \item other items
\end{enumerate}
```

But I cannot make it not indented. The best I can do is the text indented without the numbering but I don't want it to be indented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
\item[]\hspace{-\labelwidth}\hspace{-\labelsep}text (without indent)
    \item some item
    \item some more item
\item[]\hspace{-\labelwidth}\hspace{-\labelsep}text (without indent)
    \item other items
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @CELLSecret, you are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Why not this, using the `resume` key from `enumitem`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent text (without indent)
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item some item
    \item some more item
\end{enumerate}
\noindent text (without indent)
  \begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item other items
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I saw the above response first and I accepted it. Still very helpful though! (+1)